# How to autocreate incremental slugs in SQL Server 2012 web edition using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a master table called `NAMES` like so:

```
id int autoincrement,
name varchar(50),
slug varchar(50) unique
```

I would like to insert new values into this table via an insert/merge/if statement so that if the slug already exists, then the slug value gets a number appended *e.g.*

```
insert into names values('test', 'test')
```

the second time i call that command then the resultant insert would look like so

```
insert into names values('test', 'test_1')
```

and if insert another 'test' into the slug field... the resultant command would be similar to doing .

```
insert into names values('test', 'test_2')
```

I've tried to simply what i mean,. but in my real world example I would use this technique to mass insert values into my names table.

Is this possible via a T-SQL stored procedure?

Comment: It's possible through string parsing, but why?  Why not just make `slug` an `INT` and increment it instead of parsing strings?  Concatenate the fields when you're querying the data.

Comment: What about "test_42"? If it is inserted explicitly do you want to fill in around it ("test_1" ... "test_41", "test_43" ...), just insert after it ("test_43"...) or preclude the possibility of explicitly inserting a slug that ends with an underscore and digit(s)?

Comment: thanks squillman. I haven't thought of doing it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table test_table
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    name varchar(50),
    slug int
)


create procedure test_table_insert
(
    @name varchar(50)
)
as
begin
    declare @max int;;
    select @max = max(slug)
    from test_table
    where name = @name;
    if @max is null
        begin
            set @max=0;
        end;
    else
        begin
            set @max = @max+1;
        end;

    insert into test_table
    (name,slug)
    values
    (@name,@max)
end;

exec test_table_insert 'one';
exec test_table_insert 'one';
exec test_table_insert 'two';
exec test_table_insert 'two';
exec test_table_insert 'two';
exec test_table_insert 'two';
exec test_table_insert 'two';
exec test_table_insert 'two';

select id,name,concat('test_',slug) from test_table;

1   one test_0
2   one test_1
3   two test_0
4   two test_1
5   two test_2
6   two test_3
7   two test_4
8   two test_5
```